# AFTER INSERT trigger calling stored procedure which calls API, causes problem with @@IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers, webapi

I am replacing a classic ASP website and VB6 back-end process for a client. It's a pretty high-traffic site where various processes insert a record into a queue table. A couple of the processes are different web services and one process is a form on the classic ASP website. For the new process, I created an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that calls a stored procedure, which makes an API call to another server. That API call will initiate code to process the new record. Here's the `INSERT` (disclaimer: code modified to mask client identity... and make me look as intelligent as possible):

```
    -- =============================================
    -- Author:      Gary Jorgenson, RN
    -- Create date: 05/17/2021
    -- Description: notify system of New record
    -- =============================================

    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_notify_new_record] 
    ON [dbo].[TableName] 
    AFTER INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @id AS INT;
        SELECT @id = I.id FROM INSERTED I

        EXEC [dbo].[core_api_notify_new_record]
                    @record_id = @id
    END
```

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
    -- =============================================
    -- Author:      Gary Jorgenson, RN
    -- Create date: 5/16/2021
    -- Description: Notify system of new record
    -- =============================================

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_api_newrecord_notify]
        @record_id AS INT 
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @URL NVARCHAR(128) = 'https://ourwebsite.com/api/newrecord';
        DECLARE @recID AS VARCHAR(50) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @record_id);
        SET @URL = CONCAT(@url, '/',  @recID);

        DECLARE @Object AS INT;
        DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000);

        EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post', @URL,'false'

        EXEC [sp_OAMethod] @Object , 'setRequestHeader' , NULL , 'Content-Type' , 'application/json'
        EXEC [sp_OAMethod] @Object , 'responseText' , @ResponseText OUTPUT

        SELECT @ResponseText AS [Details]

        EXEC [sp_OADestroy] @Object 
    END
```

To do initial testing, I made the API controller just do a simple insert into a log table that records the record ID of the newly created record.  I tested the API locally using POSTMAN and that was successful. I then locked down the sp_OA... methods to provide only the permissions necessary, and tested the stored procedure by executing it in SSMS using the same credentials as will be used in production, and that was successful. Lastly, I enabled the `AFTER INSERT` trigger having a pretty high level of confidence that nothing could go wrong.

I was not correct.

A few minutes after turning on the trigger, a few customers called reporting that the website crashed when trying to submit the form. Working with the original website developer, we determined that his code was performing a multi-statement SQL Insert where the last statement called `@@IDENTITY` to get the new record ID. Somehow, the stored procedure and/or API call was affecting `@@IDENTITY` where it returned a null or zero value.

This makes no sense as the only other INSERT being made in the process, is behind the API controller which INSERTS a log record on a different machine, in a different instance of SQL Server.

The original website developer is changing `@@IDENTITY` to instead use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.  We're going to test and see if that alleviates the problem. The whole thing makes me nervous though as I never imagined this process would have any effect on `@@IDENTITY` since I'm not inserting any records in any tables on the local machine. I'd like to have a better understanding of what happened in this process.

Ultimate my question is, how could my process have effected `@@IDENTITY` since I didn't insert any records?

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Good point, thanks.  I'll modify the trigger to not pass any id's to the proc, and have the proc scan for new records.   Sorry question is not more clear.  I want to know how my process effected @@IDENTITY when I didn't create any new records in my process.

Comment: Also, I don't use @@IDENTITY in my code.  This was legacy code written by someone else that my new process broke. My immediate response was to ask the original  developer if he can change @@IDENTITY to something else like IDENT_CURRENT(tableName)

Comment: Even if the insert is on another machine,  in an entirely different instance of SQL Server?

Comment: ah! That makes sense.  I didn't consider unknown inserts into a system table, which prompted my post here.  My code caused something I didn't think it should have caused. I'll pass on your advice to the other developer about @@IDENTITY as I can't change his code.

Comment: There is a fundamental mistake in your trigger: it assumes there is only ever one row in `inserted`, this is simply not true, see https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/. Also, you really should not use `sp_OA...` procedure as they are ancient and have many issues, definitely don't use them in a trigger as the transaction will lock up until a response is received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be my own fault.  In the stored procedure, I had a `SELECT` at the end of the procedure that returned the API response:

```
   SELECT @ResponseText AS [Message]
```

The previous developer had code where he performed in INSERT, then queried @@IDENTITY for the new record id. Instead of getting an integer record id, he was getting the message from the API call.  He changed his code to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY` and we tested to find it still didn't work.  Digging a little deeper, we found the problem.

Comment: Output parameters are definitely your friend for a small number of values to return to the caller.

Comment: Yes,  agreed.  In this case though, it seems one problem just led to another.  I only really cared about a return value if something went wrong in the API and it returned a error message.  I commented out the select statement was planned to replace it with logic that used SQL Mail to send a message to tech support if API failed.  Then I discovered that  SQL Express (which is what my client currently uses) doesn't support SQL Mail.  I have to rethink that scenario until they upgrade to full SQL Server.

Comment: Log an even in a table, write a small windows server to read the table and send an email. Couple of hours work :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the value only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.

So the likely scenario when using `@@IDENTITY` is that the trigger is also doing an insert (maybe to a system table in your case) and therefore this new id is returned in `@@IDENTITY` back to the user - which of course is not the id they want.

I can't actually think of a case when you would want to use `@@IDENTITY`, these days you would normally use the [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause to ensure you get back exactly the id(s) you are looking for. If for some reason that is not an option then `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is a much better alternative to `@@IDENTITY`.

`IDENT_CURRENT(TableName)` is just as bad, in that the value returned is across **ALL** sessions and **ALL** scopes... you're restricting the table at the cost of widening the scope.

Note: As an aside your trigger is broken, because its assuming that `Inserted` will only contain a single record when in fact it can contain 0-N.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice.  I usually use IDENT_CURRENT( tableName ) with INSERT statements and hadn't known about OUTPUT.  I'll study up on that and will be using that from now on.

Comment: @GaryJorgenson [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current) might be of interest.